# Search textbox using checkbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, text-search

I am trying to do a text-search using a checkbox. For example, if the person selects the check box it will display the word/letter the user has entered into the search box(this word/letter will be highlighted). Say I enter "the" it will search for all "the" in the paragraph and will highlight all the "the". I already got that first part down what I am not understanding is how to make the checkbox connect with the text-search form. So when the user selects the checkbox "the" will display or whatever word/letter they enter into the search box.

I was thinking of using the if statement...

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: Why were you thinking of using the `if` statement?

Comment: its a lot to post -@abagshaw could you do a short example instead with just the text-search and the checkbox ?

Comment: What's the use of `checkbox`?

Comment: if user selects checkbox shows highlights otherwise does not @putvande

Comment: The use of the checkbox is to display all  the highlighted material in the paragraph @PraveenKumar

Comment: So it essentially highlights, is it?

Comment: So something like `$(':checkbox').on('change', function() { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // do your search thing } );`?

Comment: highlight basically is what the user enters in the search box @PraveenKumar

Comment: it will display the word or letter they have entered in the search box @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".content").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $(".content").removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

And in the CSS you need to have:

```
.highlight {background: #99f;}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt repellat sint eligendi adipisci consequuntur perspiciatis voluptate sunt id, unde aspernatur dolor impedit iure quaerat possimus nihil laboriosam, neque, accusamus ad.";
  $(".content").text(text);
  $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".content").addClass("highlight");
      $(".content").html(text.replace(/lo/gi, '<span>lo</span>'));
    } else {
      $(".content").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.check + input {display: none;}
.check:checked + input {display: inline-block;}
.highlight span {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your terms..." class="term" />
<div class="content"></div>
```

Maybe something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to interact with that checkbox you could do something like:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        // do your search thing 
    } else {
        // turn off your search thingy
    } 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx4fnyw4/)